# New soft-keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I have one question:

How can I select what soft-keyboard an edittext will load?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user chooses the input method editor (IME). You can configure the IME somewhat via `android:imeOptions` and `android:inputType` attributes in your layout XML.

Comment: but i create my own soft-keyboard because i need a key called "next", so i need that soft-keyboard be load –

Comment: You can set the action button (lower-right corner) to have a label of "Next", thereby avoiding your own soft keyboard implementation. And you absolutely cannot change what soft keyboard is displayed -- the user has to choose your IME via the Settings application.

Answer (score 0):

The InputType of the editText determines which keyboard is shown.  See [Input Type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Comment: but i create my own soft-keyboard because i need a key called "next", so i need that soft-keyboard be load

Comment: Did you look at the IME action buttons?  I've never done it, but this article http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html talks about a next action..